# Kubespray : Netchecker connectivity check fails

Tags: kubernetes, kubespray

I deployed a Kubernetes (v1.17.5) cluster on OpenStack instances using Kubespray. Those instances are CentOS 7.6.1811 qcow2 images imported in Glance.

The install was successful, and I can see my nodes and pods with kubectl commands.

I used the `deploy_netchecker` option to deploy NetChecker and test the network within my cluster, and set `network_plugin="flannel"`.
I also tried `kube_proxy_mode="iptables"`, but it doesn't seem to affect the result.
That's pretty much all the changes I did in the `k8s-cluster.yml` file.

All the pods are running, services too :

```
[centos@cl1-master-0 ~]$ kubectl get svc --all-namespaces
NAMESPACE     NAME                        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
default       kubernetes                  ClusterIP   10.233.0.1      <none>        443/TCP                  46h
default       netchecker-service          NodePort    10.233.13.213   <none>        8081:31081/TCP           46h
kube-system   coredns                     ClusterIP   10.233.0.3      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   46h
kube-system   dashboard-metrics-scraper   ClusterIP   10.233.59.12    <none>        8000/TCP                 46h
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard        ClusterIP   10.233.63.20    <none>        443/TCP                  46h
```

But netchecker API gives the following answer :

```
[root@localhost ~]# curl http://X.X.X.X:31081/api/v1/connectivity_check
{"Message":"Connectivity check fails. Reason: there are absent or outdated pods; look up the payload","Absent":["netchecker-agent-hostnet-kk56x","netchecker-agent-hostnet-klldn","netchecker-agent-hostnet-r2vqs","netchecker-agent-hostnet-wqhjs"],"Outdated":["netchecker-agent-4jsgf","netchecker-agent-c9pcf","netchecker-agent-hostnet-jzbfv","netchecker-agent-vxgpf"]}
```

For an unknown reason, I cannot access the API from a cluster node with localhost, so I used a floating IP with OpenStack.

Here are some logs from the agent :

```
[centos@cl1-master-0 ~]$ sudo vi /var/log/pods/default_netchecker-agent-vjnwl_d8290268-3ea4-4e3c-acb4-295ab162a735/netchecker-agent/0.log
{"log":"I0701 13:04:01.814246       1 agent.go:135] Response status code: 200\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2020-07-01T13:04:01.81437579Z"}
{"log":"I0701 13:04:01.814272       1 agent.go:128] Sleep for 15 second(s)\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2020-07-01T13:04:01.814393199Z"}
{"log":"I0701 13:04:16.817398       1 agent.go:55] Send payload via URL: http://netchecker-service:8081/api/v1/agents/netchecker-agent-vjnwl\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2020-07-01T13:04:16.817786735Z"}
```

```
[centos@cl1-master-0 ~]$ sudo vi /var/log/pods/default_netchecker-agent-hostnet-klldn_d5fa6e72-885f-44e1-97a6-880a25e6d6d6/netchecker-agent/0.log
{"log":"E0701 13:05:22.804428       1 agent.go:133] Error while sending info. Details: Post http://netchecker-service:8081/api/v1/agents/netchecker-agent-hostnet-klldn: dial tcp 10.233.13.213:8081: i/o timeout\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2020-07-01T13:05:22.805138032Z"}
{"log":"I0701 13:05:22.804474       1 agent.go:128] Sleep for 15 second(s)\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2020-07-01T13:05:22.805190295Z"}
{"log":"I0701 13:05:37.807140       1 agent.go:55] Send payload via URL: http://netchecker-service:8081/api/v1/agents/netchecker-agent-hostnet-klldn\n","stream":"stderr","time":"2020-07-01T13:05:37.807309111Z"}
```

Logs from the server do not indicate any error.

I tried to check DNS resolve with the following :

```
[centos@cl1-master-0 ~]$ kubectl exec -it netchecker-agent-4jsgf -- /bin/sh
/ $ nslookup kubernetes.default
Server:    169.254.25.10
Address 1: 169.254.25.10

nslookup: can't resolve 'kubernetes.default'

[centos@cl1-master-0 ~]$ kubectl exec -it netchecker-agent-4jsgf -- cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 169.254.25.10
search default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local openstacklocal
options ndots:5
```

169.254.25.10 is the IP of the nodelocaldns, but it doesn't seem to query the coredns service deployed.
When I use `nslookup netchecker-service.default.svc.cluster.local 10.233.0.3`, with the coredns IP, I get a correct answer.

What can be wrong with my configuration ?

Thanks in advance

UPDATE : The plugin `Flannel` has an [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/issues/6115) and contains a fix to apply on all nodes of the cluster. Once done, the pods successfully report back to the netchecker server.

Comment: Duplicate [this line](https://github.com/Mirantis/k8s-netchecker-agent/blob/master/helm-chart/netchecker-agent/templates/daemonset.yaml#L17) and change `hostNetwork: True` to `dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostNet`. Deploy it and let me know it it works. Remember to duplicate, dont delete the hostNetwork line

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was able to make the agents communicate by disabling the nodelocaldns, but the hostnet-agent still fail to report to the server. The hostnet agents are configured as you said, with ```hostNetwork: true``` and ```dnsPolicy: ClusterFirstWithHostnet```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE : The plugin `Flannel` has an [issue](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kubespray/issues/6115) and contains a fix to apply on all nodes of the cluster. Once done, the pods successfully report back to the netchecker server.